# How to group by month and year from a specific range?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

The data have reported values for January 2006 through January 2019. I need to compute the total number of passengers Passenger_Count per month. The dataframe should have 121 entries (10 years * 12 months, plus 1 for january 2019). The range should go from 2009 to 2019.

[image: The data]

I have been doing:

```
df.groupby(['ReportPeriod'])['Passenger_Count'].sum()
```

But it doesn't give me the right result, it gives

[image: Wrong result]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do

```
df['ReportPeriod'] = pd.to_datetime(df['ReportPeriod'])
out = df.groupby(df['ReportPeriod'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))['Passenger_Count'].sum()
```

Comment: It gives me AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values!

Comment: @Fred change str to dt ~ :-) see the update

Comment: it is working! Now if I want only from the ranges Jan 2009 to 2019 Jan, so i get 121 rows. How could I do? If you have the time. Your answer was already extremely helpful.

Comment: @Fred check `out.index = pd.to_datetime(out.index);
out = out.loc['2009-01-01' : '2019-01-31']`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df["ReportPeriod"], format="%m/%d/%Y")
df = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq="M")).sum()
```